# Deprecated "getBitmap" with API 29. Any alternative codes?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

My `onActivityResult` is not working because `getBitmap` is deprecated. Is there any alternative code to achieve this?

Here is the code that needs to be changed (any suggestions?):

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
```

The `getBitmap` is crossed out in my tooling with a message that says it's deprecated.

Comment: Being deprecated doesn't mean "doesn't work", it means that the function will be removed in a later release but it is still usable.

Answer (score 48):

This worked for me,

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            val selectedPhotoUri = data.data
            try {
                selectedPhotoUri?.let {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            this.contentResolver,
                            selectedPhotoUri
                        )
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    } else {
                        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                        val bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source) { decoder, _, _ ->
                            decoder.setTargetSampleSize(1) // shrinking by
                            decoder.isMutableRequired = true // this resolve the hardware type of bitmap problem
                        }
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it gives me result as unexpected error unsupported bitmap configuration : "Hardware"

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( contentResolver,uri)  is also depricated. :(

Comment: Rishav Singla, use this line of code.  imageBitmap = imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 29, [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%2520android.net.Uri)). Why You use `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28)`?

Comment: It requires API level 28, for lower API  use the old way

Comment: It seems to me that using older `Media.getBitmap` requires you to rotate the image based on EXIF data whereas using `ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap` does not!  I can't find anything in docs to reflect this but have tried on a couple of devices.  Anyone finding the same?

Answer (score 22):

This worked well for me in java

```
ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), pictureUri);
Bitmap bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
```

Comment: It requires API level 28, what about older API levels?

Comment: you can do it like this
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
                        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(it.contentResolver, documentUri)
                        ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                    } else {
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(it.contentResolver, documentUri)
                    }

Answer (score 22):

You can use:

```kotlin
private fun getCapturedImage(selectedPhotoUri: Uri): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28 -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
        this.contentResolver,
        selectedPhotoUri
    )
    else -> {
        val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
        ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Check the [official doc:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%2520android.net.Uri))

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   loading of images should be performed through [`ImageDecoder#createSource(ContentResolver, Uri)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder.html#createSource(android.content.ContentResolver,%2520android.net.Uri)), which offers modern features like PostProcessor.

Comment: thanks! any suggestions on how i can use that to my existing code?

Comment: @jaedstermedina the method is deprecated not removed. The alternative is the method reported in the answer. It is not related to the version of gradle or the plugin for android, it is related to adoption of api 29.

Answer (score 6):

It was evident that the `getBitmap` API doesn't work with the latest Android SDK - 29. So, this worked for me

```
Uri contentURI = data.getData();
try {
    imageView.setImageURI(contentURI);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please let me know if this doesn't work for any of you, shall other options!

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code for creating bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
     ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
     try {
         bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
} else {
     try {
     bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
     } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: it should be `>= 28`.

Comment: Both 28 and 29 should be okay since the old one deprecated in 29 and the new one came in 28.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a class for loading a Bitmap from uri:

```
public class BitmapResolver {
    private final static String TAG = "BitmapResolver";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Bitmap getBitmapLegacy(@NonNull ContentResolver contentResolver, @NonNull Uri fileUri){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, fileUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private static Bitmap getBitmapImageDecoder(@NonNull ContentResolver contentResolver, @NonNull Uri fileUri){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, fileUri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmap(@NonNull ContentResolver contentResolver, Uri fileUri){
        if (fileUri == null){
            Log.i(TAG, "returning null because URI was null");
            return null;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
            return getBitmapImageDecoder(contentResolver, fileUri);
        } else{
            return getBitmapLegacy(contentResolver, fileUri);
        }
    }
   }
```

Just to save you some time ...

Comment: Nice, now on kotlin

Comment: still not working in this code. I think the decodeBitmap method needs to run in a worker thread. Any Solution For This?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone getting  `unsupported bitmap configuration : "Hardware" error` or you need mutable bitmap for Canvas or reading pixels use this

```
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(
    ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, uri)
) { decoder, info, source ->
    decoder.allocator = ImageDecoder.ALLOCATOR_SOFTWARE
    decoder.isMutableRequired = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), pictureUri)

works fine, but to be able to use this code, mindSdkVersion should be at least 28.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

`val bitmap = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, uri)`

Comment: It requires AP 28

Answer (score -1):

For deprecated `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap()` in **API level 29**, You can use this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.error_read_image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null {
binding?.ivImage?.setImageURI(result.data?.data)}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code works for my case:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    try {
            when (requestCode) {

                //get the image with camera
                SECTIONCAMERA -> {
                    val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                  ImageView_imagePerfil.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)

                }
                //get the image in gallery
                SECTIONGALLERY -> {
                    val imageUri = data?.data
                    ImageView_imagePerfil.setImageURI(imageUri) }
            }

    } catch (e: Exception){
             e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```